# Type 'IUser' is abstract and can not be used to construct objects from dictionary values. Please register a conversion within the ValueConverter

Tags: c#, .net, graphql

Full GraphQL error (didn't fit in the title): "Type 'IUser' is abstract and can not be used to construct objects from dictionary values. Please register a conversion within the ValueConverter or for input graph types override ParseDictionary method."

I have an error message that I cannot figure out. We are upgrading our .NET Console Apps (used as APIs) from GraphQL 2.4.0 using .NET Core 3.1 and .NET Standard 2.1 helper projects to GraphQL 7.7.2 with C# .NET 8. We also went from AutoMapper 9 to 12.

Originally we tried using the GraphQL documentation at https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/migrations/ to go from v2 to v3 then v3 to v4 then v4 to v5 then v5 to v7. We punted that idea and just went all in upgrading from v2 to v7. We are in a state where our GraphQL Queries are working well but our Mutations are not.

We are using a Mutation for Inserts/Updates and our Inserts/Updates but we are popping a 400 error with the InnerException message of: "Type 'IUser' is abstract and can not be used to construct objects from dictionary values. Please register a conversion within the ValueConverter or for input graph types override ParseDictionary method."

We googled the error message and I don't get much. I do see that part of the error is shown on https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/migrations/migration4/ but I'll be honest that I'm new to GraphQL and I haven't touched .NET in 5 years. If my answer is on the migration4 link, I wouldn't know.

I don't know what the error is saying. I thought maybe there was a problem with my Field statements. We had Field("isActive", x => x.IsActive, type: typeof(BooleanGraphType)); but changed to Field("IsActive"); thinking we were on to something. But, we have the same error.

Any pointers?

Thank you!